# Python , remove a ' ' from a string in an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string

I have a result data which is in this format result: ['hellloworld@gmail.com'] , how we can remove the ' ' from the string ?

## desired result

```
[hellloworld@gmail.com]
```

Comment: Is the `single quote` a part of your string? I think the `single quote` is a symbol used to show the data type as `string`. If your data type is `integer`, for example, then there will no `single quote` in the list.

Comment: that is just to show that the data is a string type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the string

```
a = “[‘helloworld@gmail.com’]”
```

Try this:

```
a.replace(“‘“, “”)
```

More likely, you’re printing a list with a string in it. You’ll want to coerce it to a string first, then replace the quotes.